# used awk to search by unicode in txt file

Tags: awk, search, unicode

How i can  used awk to search in txt file by unicode like :

```
u+064C

u+064D
```

and please how i count results and print the number in first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using `zsh`¹, you can do:

```
SEARCH=$'\u64c' awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["SEARCH"])'
```

To print the lines that contain that character. For characters above U+FFFF, use `$'\U1F427'` (for  for instance), `\u` being limited to 4 digits, `\U` to 8 digits.

To count those lines:

```
SEARCH=$'\u64c' awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["SEARCH"]) {n++}
                     END {print n+0}'
```

`$'\u64c` will be expanded to the encoding of that U+064C character is the user's locale, for instance 0xec in a `ar_TN.iso88596` locale where the charmap is ISO-8859-6 or 0xd9 0x8c in a en_US.UTF-8 where it's UTF-8 or 0x81 0x31 0x87 0x36 in `zh_CN.gb18030` where it's GB18030.

If the locale's charset doesn't have that character, the command is aborted with a *`zsh: character not in range`* error.

With some awk implementations and on some systems (where the wchar_t maps to Unicode code points) and in locales where the charmap is multibyte (such as UTF-8 or GB18030 above), `sprintf("%c", 0x64c)` returns the encoding of the U+064C character. That's the case of GNU `awk` on GNU systems at least. In those cases, you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{search = sprintf("%c", 0x64c)}
     index($0, search)'
```

In multibyte locales where the U+064C character doesn't exist, I find that `gawk`'s `sprintf("%c", 0x64c)` returns the 0x4c byte instead (0x64c % 0x100) (same in singlebyte locales regardless of whether U+064C exists or not in the locale's charset).

---

<sup>¹ some other shells have since added support for `$'\uXXXX'` as well, but with varying behaviour when it comes to which charset the character is encoded in and what happens if the charset doesn't have the character.</sup>

Comment: thank you, it's work, i tested it to Find two consecutive letters  but not work, like sprintf("%c", 0x64c 0x623), what the problem please .

Comment: @alomndo, not sure what you mean by unicode unicode, but if you want a string of two characters expressed by their Unicode code point, you'd need `sprintf("%c%c", 0x64c, 0x623)` or `$'\u64c\u623'` in `zsh`.

Comment: thank you, it's not get two consecutive letters. it's get any line containt the two letters. like "abc" or "bca" or "cab", i want consecutive "abc" only.

Comment: @alomndo, then `first = sprintf(...); second = sprintf(...)` and `index($0, first) && index($0, second)`.